# How to differentiate between sdcard and usb mount in android programatically

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using the following code for getting the external storage mounted in android device.

```
 val storageManager = CHSSystemApplication.instance.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE) as StorageManager?
        storageManager?.storageVolumes
```

I mount the sd card and USB it returns the two storage volume.
Is there any way we can differentiate between sd card volume and USB.